# difference of the arithmetical sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Choose the first element and the difference of the arithmetical sequence, where you know that

$$a_3+a_5+a_7=-12, a_3*a_4*a_5=-90$$ 
Choose the first element and the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $$a_3=a_1+2d,a_4=a_1+3d,a_5=a_1+4d,a_7=a_1+6d$$ we get the system
$$3a_1+12d=-12$$
and

$$(a_1+2d)(a_1+3d)(a_1+4d)=-90$$
Can you solve this=